# df -h yielding what looks like a strange output: /home, /dev, and /net have 0% free space

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, malware, virus

I have a MacBook Pro with 1 TB of disk space.

When I run `df -h` I get the following:

[image]

It tells me I have 702 GiB available on / which I suspect is true -- but nothing on /home.

Do I have a virus or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a virus or not, but the `df` listing is 100% legitimate and normal.